# How can I auto-import a certain file of the project by unimport?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am using the plugin named [Unimport](https://github.com/unjs/unimport) which is used for auto-import modules from third-part libs or current project. It was used in `nuxt` and can be configired in `nuxt.config.ts` like:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  imports: {
    // Auto-import pinia stores defined in `~/stores`
    dirs: ['stores']
  }
}
```

`Unimport` will generate a declaration file named `unimport.d.ts`:

```
export {}
declare global {
  const globalStore: typeof import('/home/stores/globalStore')['globalStore']
}
```

Modules under `stores` dir can be auto-imported correctly, but if I already created a entry file of the `stores` dir and exports other modules in it:

```
export * from './globalStore'
```

Expect `globalStore` can be imported from `stores/index.ts` file instead of `stores/globalStore.ts`, so I want to specify the auto-import of a particular file.

`Unimport` only provide a option named `dirs` for auto-import all files, how can I auto-import a certain file ?